# Is it possible to update layer source in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

I've loaded a few shapefiles as layers in QGIS, and I'd like to make a duplicate of the project and all associated shapefiles into a single directory. However, all of the layer sources are still pointing to the original shapefiles.

Is there an easy way to update the paths to the duplicated shapefiles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by editing the project file in a text editor.

1. Open the .QGS project file in a text editor, (e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).
2. Update all the necessary paths.
3. Save changes ("Save as" a new file name if you want to make sure the original isn't damaged) and exit the text editor.